# Using netcat to allow users to use shell

Tags: c, linux, unix, netcat

I'm not really sure where to start. I'm supposed to use netcat to allow anyone to access my shell remotely in C. I know I need to need to use sockets, but not sure what else. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Basically when I execute the program, I want it to open "nc -l  1234", take in commands from the client and respond. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
mkfifo temp
nc -l 1234 < temp 2>&1 | /bin/sh > temp 2>&1
```

Comment: when I replace sh with ./shell (my executable) it doesn't work. What do I need to change?

Comment: Try `nc -l 1234 < temp 2>&1 | ./shell > temp 2>&1`

Comment: so do I need to read from a socket or something in my server shell? is that how that works. or is this just more of a hack and I should go another route?

Comment: because I'm getting this error: write error: Bad file descriptor

Comment: Huh?  Are you sure that your `netcat` program is error free and that you're correctly creating the named pipe?

Comment: does my ./shell program need to have pipes and sockets to work in this situation is basically what I'm asking.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  But its stdin and stdout need to be compatible with pipes.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
$nc -l 1234 -e /bin/bash -i  (server)

$nc x.x.x.x 1234  (client)
```

We have created a netcat server and indicated it to run /bin/bash command when connection is successful.

This is a good reference for it . (using c)

```
http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~aviv/classes/f12/cs43/labs/lab4/lab4.pdf
```

Comment: I think you need to have `'/bin/bash -i'` in quotes

Comment: My school's server has an earlier version of NC, so I can't use the -e flag.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll spend some time with it.